Unable to embed an external url in iframe in an lwc which needs certificate to access
I am trying to embed an external url in my lwc as an iframe. The external url needs a certificate and that certificate i have added in certificate and keys in setup. But I am unable to access that url.
I tried setting the iframe with following -  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms"
Also added the certificate as API certificate. But it did not worked.
To show the functionality that is present in the external link.
